# Popen command doesn't run the code in the cluster

Tags: python, subprocess, slurm

I want to run a python code which sends another bash code to a cluster (slurm). For some reason, the bash code doesn't run but I get no errors at all (I think that python sends the job because I can retrieve the ID number of the job).

Inside the script, I defined "command" to be the command to be executed. It calls to another bash script "svm_run.sh" which receives two parameters "path/fit" and "runname".

```
import subprocess as sp


command = '/home/saarb/SVM/svm/RUNS/svm_run.sh ' + runname + ' ' + path + '/fit'

ID = sp.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, universal_newlines=True).communicate()[0]

ID = ID.split()[-1].strip()
```

However, when I use the exact same lines in python prompt (not in script) on the front end computer I have no problems at all.

Here is the bash code "svm_run.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash
#
cd ..

name=$1
path=$2
job_name=${name}


output_dir=/home/saarb/SVM/svm/output/${path}
input_dir=/home/saarb/SVM/svm/data/${path}

cat > sbatch_script.${job_name}.$$ << EOF
#!/bin/bash
#

#SBATCH --job-name=${job_name}
#SBATCH --output=${output_dir}/${job_name}.sc
#SBATCH --error=${output_dir}/${job_name}.sc
#SBATCH --partition=serial
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --qos=serial



date 

# mpiexec ./svm.x ${path}/${name} > ${job_name}.out
mpiexec ./svm.x ${path}/${name}

echo "done!"
date
\rm sbatch_script.${job_name}.$$

EOF

sbatch sbatch_script.${job_name}.$$
```

Comment: Are you running on Linux? If so, you cannot provide command and arguments in the same string, They should be provided as a list of strings.

Comment: yeah, I work on linux. I tried your suggestions via split ( command= command.split() ) but it didn't work. not even on the front end.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. If you set `shell=True` (as you did), then the command and args should be in a string (as you originally had it). So you aren't seeing any `slurm` output files produced?

Comment: No I don’t see. But for a second or two I can see the job (the bash script) in pending status and then it disappears